# how to load 3rd party lua libs (installed via luarocks) into haproxy

Tags: lua, haproxy

I'm writing lua script that is going to run inside `HAproxy` using it's Lua API.

My script is using `socket` package which I want to install on my machine.

Currently I'm running inside docker and my dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM haproxy:1.7

RUN apt-get update -y &&  apt-get install curl luarocks -y
RUN luarocks install luasocket

EXPOSE 80 9000

COPY 500error.json.http /etc/haproxy/errorfiles/
COPY hello_world.lua /etc/haproxy/scripts/
```

my script have the next line:

```
local http = require('socket.http')
```

which works okay when running lua interpreter but not when running haproxy:

```
[ALERT] 298/104833 (8) : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:5] : lua runtime error: /etc/haproxy/scripts/hello_world.lua:1: module 'socket.http' not found:
```

How should I load this correctly to haproxy?

Comment: While this isn't the cause of the error, you may subsequently find that you are not be able to use `socket.http` with HAProxy, if it performs any blocking operations.  It has been a while since I did any intense Lua programming with HAProxy, but I remember doing remote HTTP requests "by hand," using HAProxy's built in Lua sockets capability to send raw HTTP requests built by my code, and parsing the responses with regexes, and I had to use hard-coded IP addresses since I no asynchronous DNS capability. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can print `package.path` and `package.cpath` values just before require luasocket module.

This values is where lua store paths to load a library.

Comment: Ah... the implication being that the version of Lua compiled into HAproxy may be looking somewhere different from where the default local Lua interpreter is looking.  With HAProxy you *might* need write these to syslog to see the output, e.g. `core.Alert("package search path is " .. package.path);`